# od: Put offset n to n of a hexdump to a file in proper hexdump -C (hex+ASCII) format

Tags: shell, command-line

I have a 155GB canonical hex+ASCII hexdump

```
  hexdump -C blah > dump.dp
```

Then ran:

```
strings dump.dp | grep -bo 'XXXX' > found.txt
```

So now, that file contains the string's hex offset in the file, e.g. [2255252:XXXX]. Now, I need to get from hex offset 2254252 to 2255600 into a new file.

Now, I'm trying to redirect the output to a file so that it looks like the original hexdump with hex and ASCII, e.g.

```
00000000 41 42 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 43 |A B . . . . . . . . . . . . . C|
```

However, when i run

```
od -j 0x2254252 -N 218714 -v -x dump.dp > chunk1.txt
```

The output looks like

```
 2254252 2030 3030 2030 4030 4040
```

What can I do to make it look like hexdump's hex+ASCII  instead of that?

Comment: You're running `grep -bo` on `strings` applied to a hex dump?! And then want to run `od` on the hex dump!? Are you sure you don't mean `grep -bo XXXX blah` and `od -j... blah`?

Comment: `hexdump` has `-s` `-n` for `od`'s `-j` and `-n`.

Comment: Thanks! I just got done getting the pipes [7c] and values in between formatted correctly so I could make it look like a normal hexdump again (starting at offset x and ending at offset y of blah). This is fixed

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Restart the numbering so that the offsets for the interesting portion start at 0? Why are you using `od` and not `hexdump`?

Comment: @Giles I agree that the reason is unclear, although I'd like to see an answer for a different reason: I have a system with `od` but not `hexdump`.

Comment: tl;dr @jpaugh if you ask ill try to answer. for my task i had to hexdump a large binary file then get from addrs x to y out of it, with the ascii fun and all. i realized i could just find the offset of the magic string (get a count of n bytes), dd it out for a y size binary file then hexdump from there. i manually had to figure out the starting and ending byte count for the magic strings which was the surprisingly simple part ( it was something like each line used 32 bytes so from ascii 0xDEADBEEF to 0xDEAF0000 used x bytes).  probably could have been "done smarter" but i needed results

Comment: @grepNstepN I managed to use `xxd` instead, but thanks. Nevertheless, adding an answer to your question might help future readers.